# Logon problems due to multiple accounts or OpenIDs "Oops! Something Bad Happened"

Tags: support

I'm having problems with the logon process as I appear to have two accounts - depending on how I've logged in (when I do manage to login) I have different reputation and different community memberships
One of the things that happens however quite often is when I get to the Login page and click StackExchange open ID login - I get [image: Opps Something Bad Happened]
This Meta forum appears to let me logon without a problem - yet the other forums within StackExchange intermittantly do not
I have found that I have two StackExchange accounts , one linked to a Google open id and one link to both a Facebook Open ID and a Stackexchange Open ID

When I try to merge accounts using either of these logons - it says - the other account is in use so I can only Swap to the other account

However I want SO to merge the two accounts, as I believe that these dual accounts is what is causing the error message.

Comment: Can you clarify your very last sentence: *"Oh yes they are merged ... but I appear to have different membership and reputations depending on which OpenID I used... maybe"*? What do you mean "they are merged"? Also: "maybe"? In any case have you gone through the process at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/230261?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly have two accounts. Use the contact us link, add profiles for *both* accounts you have used here (they have different gravatars) and request a merger of the accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jason going through this process did fix this problem and the Oops message no longer appears to be occurring 
meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/230261?

I had two accounts ( a joined stackexchange/facebook OPENID ) account and a Google account 
When I try and add another login method it says - no you must logon - so I could merge them  - but the link Jason posted is automated and worked for me

I have three openIDs, Google, Facebook and StackExchange
The Facebook and StackExchange have been linked on StackExchange - but not the Google account

Here is one reputation/membership - (Facebook/Stackexchange)

### [image: Rep Membership with logon 1 StackExchange and Facebook]

and here is the other - when logged on with Google

[image: Rep Membership with logon 2 Google]

Comment: So next try - I logged out of all the accounts Google, Facebook and StackExchange - I then logged in with the Facebook account and tried to link the Google account - it gave me the message 
Switch Users On Meta Stack Exchange
 Google (XXXXXX@gmail.com) belongs to another user (Ross) 
You can log in as Ross or cancel to stay logged in as Ross   - so it appears I cant link them   However logging out of everything does appear to fix the "Oops error message"